# equivalent of assoc-in(clojure) in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, merge, clojure, overwrite

I am trying to find an equivalent of assoc-in (clojure) in scala. I am trying to convert

```
(defn- organiseDataByTradeId [data]
(reduce #(let [a (assoc-in %1 
                        [(%2 "internaltradeid") (read-string (%2 "paramseqnum")) "levelcols"] 
                        (reduce (fn [m k](assoc m k (get %2 k))) 
                                {} 
                                (string/split xmlLevelAttributesStr #",")))
            b (assoc-in a



                      [(%2 "internaltradeid") (read-string (%2 "paramseqnum")) "subLevelCols" (read-string (%2 "cashflowseqnum"))]
                         (reduce (fn [m k] (assoc m k (get %2 k))) 
                                {} 
                                (string/split xmlSubLevelAttributesStr #","))               
                        )] 
            b)
      {}
      data))
```

to scala.
Have tried this :

```
def organiseDataByTradeId(data: List[Map[String, String]]) = {
    data.map { entry => Map(entry("internaltradeid") -> Map(entry("paramseqnum").toInt -> Map("levelcols" -> (xmlLevelAttributesStr.split(",")).map{key=> (key,entry(key))}.toMap,
        "subLevelCols" -> Map(entry("cashflowseqnum").asInstanceOf[String].toInt -> (xmlSubLevelAttributesStr.split(",")).map{key=> (key,entry(key))}.toMap)))) }

  }
```

Not sure how to merge the list of maps I got without overwriting.
Here *data* **List[Map[String,String]]** is basically describing a table.Each entry is a row.Column names are keys of the maps and values are values.**xmlLevelAttributeStr** and **xmlSubLevelAttributeStr** are two Strings where column names are separated by comma.
I am fairly new to scala. I converted each row(Map[String,String]) to a scala Map and now not sure how to merge them so that previous data is not overwritten and behaves exactly as the clojure code.Also I am not allowed to use external libraries such as scalaz.

Comment: 1. You are not allowed due to job restrictions or interview requirements? 2. Without external libraries I would either split it into several functions, combine nested `map`, `flatMap` and `updated` or implement my own `Traversal`, `Optional` optics.

Comment: job restrictions. I am new to scala ,hence yet not sure how to take advantage of the powerful pattern matching support.I am not sure I understood what you said,can you please provide a sample implementation for the same? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This Clojure code is not a good pattern to copy: it has a lot of duplication, and little explanation of what it is doing. I would write it more like this:

```
(defn- organiseDataByTradeId [data]
  (let [level-reader (fn [attr-list]
                       (let [levels (string/split attr-list #",")]
                         (fn [item]
                           (into {} (for [level levels]
                                      [level (get item level)])))))
        attr-levels (level-reader xmlLevelAttributesStr)
        sub-levels (level-reader xmlSubLevelAttributesStr)]
    (reduce (fn [acc item]
              (update-in acc [(item "internaltradeid"),
                              (read-string (item "paramseqnum"))]
                         (fn [trade]
                           (-> trade
                               (assoc "levelcols" (attr-levels item))
                               (assoc-in ["subLevelCols", (read-string (item "cashflowseqnum"))]
                                         (sub-levels item))))))
            {}, data)))
```

It's more lines of code than your original, but I've taken the opportunity to name a number of useful concepts and extract the repetition into a local function so that it's more self-explanatory.

It's even easier if you know there will be no duplication of internaltradeid: you can simply generate a number of independent maps and merge them together:

```
(defn- organiseDataByTradeId [data]
  (let [level-reader (fn [attr-list]
                       (let [levels (string/split attr-list #",")]
                         (fn [item]
                           (into {} (for [level levels]
                                      [level (get item level)])))))
        attr-levels (level-reader xmlLevelAttributesStr)
        sub-levels (level-reader xmlSubLevelAttributesStr)]
    (apply merge (for [item data]
                   {(item "internaltradeid")
                    {(read-string (item "paramseqnum"))
                     {"levelcols" (attr-levels item),
                      "subLevelCols" {(read-string (item "cashflowseqnum")) (sub-levels item)}}}}))))
```

But really, neither of these approaches will work well in Scala, because Scala has a different data modeling philosophy than Clojure does. Clojure encourages loosely-defined heterogeneous maps like this, where Scala would prefer that your maps be homogeneous. When you will have data mixing multiple types, Scala suggests you define a class (or perhaps a case class - I'm no Scala expert) and then create instances of that class.

So here you'd want a `Map[String, Map[Int, TradeInfo]]`, where `TradeInfo` is a class with two fields, `levelcols : List[Attribute]`, and `subLevelCols` as some sort of pair (or perhaps a single-element map) containing a `cashflowseqnum` and another `List[Attribute]`.

Once you've modeled your data in the Scala way, you'll be quite far away from using anything that looks like `assoc-in` because your data won't be a single giant map, so the question won't arise.